# What are the new PC to monitor connector I saw

Tags: hdmi

I am getting a new video card. I want to connect my PC to 2 monitors. I used the HDMI port.

Then I saw 2 other ports. I recoqnize that one of them is DVI. The other one is very new. I wonder what it is.

It looks like HDMI connector. I will put photograph here.

Okay this is how it looks like

[image]

It's between HDMI and DVI

Comment: Instead of a blurry picture just provide us the information on the hardware itself.

Comment: what do you mean? Also because it must be popular then it can only mean  display port like what the answer said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) which looks pretty similar to HDMI on first look.

[image: Displayport-Connector taken from Wikipedia]